# Apache doesn't respond

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a AWS Lightsail Bitnami LAMP 7.4.27-16 machine that every night stops responding at random time. I installed LetsEncrypt certificate and vsftpd for a new specific ftp user.

On the machine all seems working properly. The server is listening, cpu is ok, ram is ok, I can connect to it by SSH. Apache and MariaDb services are running. Only the website load infinitely (http or https).

These are the last access_log lines:

```
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:24 +0000] "GET //website/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7120
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:25 +0000] "GET //wp/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7115
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:25 +0000] "GET //news/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7117
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:25 +0000] "GET //2020/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7117
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:25 +0000] "GET //2019/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7117
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:25 +0000] "GET //shop/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7117
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:26 +0000] "GET //wp1/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7116
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:26 +0000] "GET //test/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7117
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:26 +0000] "GET //wp2/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7116
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:26 +0000] "GET //site/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7117
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:26 +0000] "GET //cms/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7116
45.95.169.230 - - [11/Mar/2022:02:59:27 +0000] "GET //sito/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 7117
3.208.15.15 - - [11/Mar/2022:03:09:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 234
3.208.15.15 - - [11/Mar/2022:03:09:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2760
```

and these the error_log:

```
[Thu Mar 10 00:00:04.415191 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31589:tid 140507846433664] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Thu Mar 10 00:00:04.442377 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31589:tid 140507846433664] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 10 00:00:04.442392 2022] [core:notice] [pid 31589:tid 140507846433664] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf'
[Fri Mar 11 00:00:03.441124 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31589:tid 140507846433664] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Fri Mar 11 00:00:03.458966 2022] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 31589:tid 140507846433664] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1d configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 11 00:00:03.458981 2022] [core:notice] [pid 31589:tid 140507846433664] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf'
[Fri Mar 11 03:09:55.831036 2022] [ssl:error] [pid 30732:tid 140507162339072] [client 3.208.15.15:33716] AH02042: rejecting client initiated renegotiation
```

No error in MySql log.

What can I do now? There are some commands or logs to check?

Comment: How'd ya fix it?